# Are the privileges on underlying table automatically passed on to any views created on the table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, security

If a user has `SELECT`, `INSERT` privileges on the underlying table of a view, would he automatically have the same privileges on views (created on the table) as well or does he need to be granted those?

For instance, suppose Bob has `INSERT` privileges on the table EMPLOYEES. Does he also have `INSERT` privileges on a view EMPLOYEENAMES which has only the names of the employees?

PLEASE NOTE: I am working on oracle express 11g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the privileges are not inherited (which would be rather problematic when you're joining multiple tables or when you are calling functions).  The views are separate objects so the grants are separate as well.

Comment: Thanks Justin. So if I understood correctly, the privileges are not inherited from underlying table, even if the view has been created only from that table itself?

Comment: @R.S.K - Correct.  Privileges are never inherited.