# Privileges on views/synonyms vs on underlying tables

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, privileges, synonym

Referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672116/are-the-privileges-on-underlying-table-automatically-passed-on-to-any-views-crea) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/devguide/cdevcsecureprivileges.html)

Would a user need both `SELECT /INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE`, etc. privileges on the view AND on the underlying table to be able to perform these actions ? Or privileges on EITHER table/view is enough ?

In other words, consider a user A owning the table T and the view V (constructed from T). Can a user B with `SELECT` right on V execute a `SELECT` if he does not `SELECT` right on T, and vice-versa ? If he could, wouldn't that mean the View privilege "overrides" the table privilege, as A does not give him right over T ?

**Update**

In a related question, how about synonym ? From what I understand in a book,  users need both `SELECT` privileges on the synonym and the underlying table. This will be different from views.

On the other hand, [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21642/privileges.htm#TTSQL343) seems to indicate that synonyms behave similar to views.

> A user can be granted the SELECT privilege on a synonym or a view
>   without being explicitly granted the SELECT privilege on the
>   originating table

**Update 2**

Following everyone's answer that we only need the privileges on view to select the table (at least what the view sees from the table) and no privilege on table is needed, let's consider this scenario :

> - Table T belongs to A
> - A GRANT SELECT ON T to B (without GRANT OPTION)
> - B CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT * FROM A.T
> - B GRANT SELECT ON V TO C
> - C performing SELECT * FROM B.V

According to what you have said, C will be able to select from V, therefore equivalent to selecting from T. Is it that cheating ? B is effectively letting C seeing A.T although C does not have the right on T and B does not have GRANT OPTION. Is there a security hole somewhere ?

Comment: You should differentiate between third user and owner of the view.  When a user use a view, he needs privileges only on the view which the owner of the view give to the user. The owner of the view has to have  privileges to the tables used from this view. And he has to have privilege to grant these privileges (grant option) or have to own the tables, [GRANT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm)

Comment: Lets have 3 users: t_owner owns the table, v_owner owns the view and n_user. To create the view, the v_owner needs select privilege on the tables used in view from t_owner. To select from view the n_user needs select privilege on the view from. To grant this privilege the v_owner needs grants from t_owner. And now what should be done is: from t_owner  GRANT SELECT ON table_name TO v_owner WITH GRANT OPTION; , from v_owner GRANT SELECT ON view_name TO n_user;

Comment: Thanks all. I have updated my question for more details. Feel free to elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fundamental uses of views is to protect privacy. A base table may have confidential information that some users don't need to see (for example, in an employee table, you may have salary). Some users need access to query (select), or to update, only certain fields from the base table, without having access to the full information. For example: select phone number, or update address (but no access to see salary or bonus). Then one would create a view and give those users "select" and "update" privileges on the view only, and not on the base table. (The select still goes against the base table, but the COLUMNS will be limited to those included in the view... updates can/will be made to the base table, but again, only for values in the columns included in the view.) The view can limit not only the columns, but also the rows - for example, with a WHERE clause in the view, you may exclude the CEO from the view completely.

So, one of the main uses of views is based exactly on that: some users may have privileges on the view, but not on the base table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Usually the view runs as the view owner, and the user runs with permission on the view.  So user b only needs access to the view.

However when looking at this sort of question, you may want to look into row level security as well.  This works by granting access to a portion of the table to a given user or group (i.e. effectively enforcing where clauses at the end of queries).  Depending on your use case, it may be simpler or more complex to manage.